# image selection not working properly in xzoom plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement zoom gallery effect in a project. I am trying to use "xzoom" plugin for this. Zooming of image working fine. But when I select next image it's not getting opened inside the xzoom-container. instead it is getting opened as a separate window.

My code is as below:

```
 <spring:url value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" var="jquery" />
    <script src="${jquery}"></script>
    <spring:url value="/resources/css/xzoom.css" var="smoothproductscs" />
    <link href="${smoothproductscs}" rel="stylesheet" media="all"/>
    <spring:url value="/resources/js/xzoom.min.js" var="smoothprod" />
            <script src="${smoothprod}"></script>

     <script>
             $(document).ready(function (){
                $(".xzoom").xzoom({tint: '#333', Xoffset: 15});
             });
    </script>

    <%
     if(rs.next()){
    %>
    <div class="xzoom-container">
    <img class="xzoom" id="xzoom-default" alt=""src="imagesa/<%= rs.getString("IMGNAME") %>" width="450" xoriginal="imagesa/<%= rs.getString("IMGNAME") %>" />
    <div class="xzoom-thumbs">
      <a href="imagesa/<%= rs.getString("IMGNAME") %>">
       <img class="xzoom-gallery" width="80" src="imagesa/<%= rs.getString("IMGNAME") %>"  xpreview="imagesa/<%= rs.getString("IMGNAME") %>">
      </a>

        <% while(rs.next()){%>

        <a href="imagesa/<%= rs.getString("IMGNAME") %>">
        <img class="xzoom-gallery" width="80" src="imagesa/<%= rs.getString("IMGNAME") %>">
      </a>

 <% }
    } %>
     </div>
     </div>
```

any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change xzoom initialization code from:

```
$(".xzoom").xzoom({tint: '#333', Xoffset: 15});
```

to this one:

```
$(".xzoom, .xzoom-gallery").xzoom({tint: '#333', Xoffset: 15});
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But could you please explain it a bit?

Comment: There is two ways how xZoom works with jQuery selectors. For example, initialize with 1 class name `$(".xzoom").xzoom();` Or Initialize with 2 and more class names `$(".xzoom, .xzoom-gallery").xzoom();` and they are different. More information you can read in [manual](https://github.com/payalord/xZoom/blob/master/doc/manual.md)